# Negation with "should be"

Tags: negation, subordinate-clauses, as

I wonder if the as clause in this sentence should be negated.

> She is not curious in the least, as she should be.

or

> She is not curious in the least, as she should not be.

Or are they both correct?

### Edit

To be more specific: I am unsure about whether an as clause needs to be negated if the main clause is in negation. To borrow a real-life example with a slight change:

> [T]he former Heisman winner is sure of where he belongs on the field—as he should be.

This is a sentence from a sports news outlet. If the main clause were negative, should the as clause also be negated?

> [T]he former Heisman winner is **not** sure of where he belongs on the field—as he should **(not) be**.

Comment: Both are somewhat *stilted* language, but both are correct.  Although with the second you could use "as she should be" to indicate the negative condition is as expected.  Still, to avoid this question being closed, you should add more detail why you find this confusing or difficult.

Comment: Please add more information explaining what you want to say, and more about what your questions is. It is often useful to explain *why* you have the question. In this case, it's not clear what you want to negate. You want to negate the negatively-polarized main clause? Is your question about whether it is grammatical to use one or both options, or whether one of both of them is clear, or what? Voting to close as lacking information at this point. Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: If you are asking to reopen the question I would suggest adding much more detail: are you writing something? (what is the context and what do you want to express?) reading something? (source? original text?) is this a test?